# Android SQLite crashing

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm trying to make an app where as you click on the button "dodaj" it saves the values from the editText forms and it then saves them into a database.
But I'm having a hard time with this onClickListener. Every time I click on the button "dodaj" it crashes the app at db.addToDB...

```
dodaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.potrdi); 
dodaj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {                                        
            if (predmet.getText() != null) {
                naslov = predmet.getText().toString();
            }
            if (snov1.getText() != null) {
                prvi = snov1.getText().toString();  
            }
            if (snov2.getText() != null) {
                drugi = snov2.getText().toString(); 
            }
            if (snov3.getText() != null) {
                tretji = snov3.getText().toString();    
            }
            if (snov4.getText() != null) {
                cetrti = snov4.getText().toString();    
            }
            if (snov5.getText() != null) {
                peti = snov5.getText().toString();  
            }           
            db.addToDB (naslov, prvi, drugi, tretji, cetrti, peti); //error here
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Here is the code for adding items to the database:

```
int addToDB(String ime_predmeta, String snov_1, String snov_2, String snov_3, String     snov_4, String snov_5)
{

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    if (ime_predmeta != null)
        {cv.put(DatabaseManager.PREDMET, ime_predmeta);}
    if (snov_1 != null)
        {cv.put(DatabaseManager.SNOV1, snov_1);}
    if (snov_2 != null)
        {cv.put(DatabaseManager.SNOV2, snov_2);}
    if (snov_3 != null)
        {cv.put(DatabaseManager.SNOV3, snov_3);}
    if (snov_4 != null)
        {cv.put(DatabaseManager.SNOV4, snov_4);}
    if (snov_5 != null)
        {cv.put(DatabaseManager.SNOV5, snov_5);}

    open(); 
    return (int)db.insert(DatabaseManager.TABELA, null, cv);
}
```

The LogCat also showed that something is wrong with my method for opening the database:

```
void open() {
    db = dbManager.getWritableDatabase(); //error here as well
}
```

StackTrace :

```
05-05 18:39:51.510: E/ThermalEngine(215): [GPU_MON] ACTION: GPU - [GPU_MON] Setting GPU[0] to 450000000
05-05 18:40:00.720: E/SQLiteLog(5207): (1) near "TABLEdodajanje": syntax error
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEdodajanje": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEdodajanje (ime_predmeta VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY snov_1 VARCHARsnov_2 VARCHARsnov_3 VARCHARsnov_4 VARCHARsnov_5 VARCHAR);
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at si.centrih.organizatorucenja.DatabaseManager.onCreate(DatabaseManager.java:39)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at si.centrih.organizatorucenja.DatabaseHandler.open(DatabaseHandler.java:19)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at si.centrih.organizatorucenja.DatabaseHandler.addToDB(DatabaseHandler.java:30)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at si.centrih.organizatorucenja.Potek_izbira$1.onClick(Potek_izbira.java:61)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17728)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
05-05 18:40:00.740: E/AndroidRuntime(5207):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 18:40:04.130: E/InputMethodService(1035): Unexpected null in startExtractingText : mExtractedText = null, input connection = com.android.internal.view.InputConnectionWrapper@422bc0c8
05-05 18:40:05.490: E/qcom_sensors_hal(700): hal_wait_for_response: pthread_cond_timedwait() rc=110 (cond: 0)
05-05 18:40:05.490: E/qcom_sensors_hal(700): hal_time_req_add: ERROR: No response from request 2
05-05 18:40:06.130: E/InputMethodService(1035): Unexpected null in startExtractingText : mExtractedText = null, input connection = com.android.internal.view.InputConnectionWrapper@422bc0c8
05-05 18:40:06.350: E/InputMethodService(1035): Unexpected null in startExtractingText : mExtractedText = null, input connection = com.android.internal.view.InputConnectionWrapper@422bc0c8
```

Comment: Can you post the actual log cat output.

Comment: "error here as well" -- thanks. And the error is?

Comment: Looks like a typographical error to me. "TABLEdodajanje" should be "TABLE dodajanje".

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors in your `CREATE TABLE` SQL in database helper `onCreate()`. Missing punctuation and whitespace:

```
CREATE TABLEdodajanje (ime_predmeta VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY snov_1 VARCHARsnov_2 VARCHARsnov_3 VARCHARsnov_4 VARCHARsnov_5 VARCHAR)
```

should be something like

```
CREATE TABLE dodajanje (ime_predmeta VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, snov_1 VARCHAR, snov_2 VARCHAR, snov_3 VARCHAR, snov_4 VARCHAR, snov_5 VARCHAR)
```

Comment: So, what's the next problem?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app and run the app again.

Uninstalling the app will delete already existing database and values that app uses. Re installation will create new fresh database.

Comment: This isn't the solution. There is no database since `onCreate()` throws.

Comment: ok. I faced similar problems with sqlite database when I changed the schema of the tables.  The problem was due to old values and issue resolved when I reinstalled. So I suggest this solution. Thank u.

Comment: I will remove my answer if this is not helpful.